# Passing in, retrieving, and setting restrictions of User from Post - Comment model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I'm attempting to set limits on the amount of commenting users can do on particular post during the day. I have implemented the following (successfully) in my Post model to limit the amount of Posts they can create.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  validate :daily_limit, :on => :create
  def daily_limit
      # Small limit for users who just sign up
      if author.created_at >= 14.days.ago
        if author.created_posts.today.count >= 4
           errors.add(:base, "Exceeds Your Daily Trial Period Limit(4)")
        end
      else
        if author.created_posts.today.count >= author.post_limit_day
           errors.add(:base, "Exceeds Your Daily Limit")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But, when I attempt to add similar restrictions to my Comment model

```
class PostComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :daily_limit, :on => :create
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user

  def daily_limit
      # Small limit for users who just sign up
      if user.posted_comments.today.count >= 2
        errors.add(:base, "Exceeds Your Daily Trial Period Limit(4)")
      end 
  end
end
```

I am greeted with a `undefined method 'posted_comments' for nil:NilClass` error.  I don't believe my user_id is being passed into my model correctly in order to access it with something like `user.posted_comments.today.count>=2`

My create action in my post_comments controller is as follows:

```
class PostCommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @post_comment = @post.post_comments.create(post_comment_params)
    @post_comment.user = current_user
    if @post_comment.save
      redirect_to @post
    else 
      flash[:alert] = "Comment Not Added"
      redirect_to @post
    end
  end
end
```

and the my hacked down User model is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_posts, class_name: 'Post', :foreign_key => "author_id",   
  dependent: :destroy

  has_many :posted_comments, class_name: 'PostComment', :foreign_key =>"user_id", dependent: :destroy 
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the user after "create" in your controller

```
@post_comment = @post.post_comments.create(post_comment_params)  
@post_comment.user = current_user
```

Try this:

```
@post_comment = @post.post_comments.build(post_comment_params)
@post_comment.user = current_user
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked wonderfully.  Will I have to call .save! afterwards?  It seems to be working without.

Comment: You are saving it in the controller `if @post_comment.save`

Comment: Thanks. I have been staring at this problem too long it seems.